# Изменение свойства стиля кнопками

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `transform: scale`

```
table#pixel_canvas {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Как можно реализовать изменение `scale(1)` по нажатию на кнопки `(+ & -)` с шагом в `0.1` ?

Comment: Вынесите стиль элемента инлайном и меняйте с помощью JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я реализовал это данным образом:

```js
let size = 1
const step = 0.1
const block = document.querySelector('div')

document.querySelector('#minus').addEventListener('click', () => {
  size -= step;
  block.style.transform = `scale(${size})`
})

document.querySelector('#plus').addEventListener('click', () => {
  size += step;
  block.style.transform = `scale(${size})`
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<br><br><br>
<div></div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mark-minerov/pen/oNjXbRM)